# Is there any search option which lets you search for which products are not showing on one of your websites?

Tags: search

I am working with a company that is selling products in several different countries. Right now I am making sure that all products that are for sale in country 1 also appears on the web page for country 2. The problem is that there is a big backlog, so I am sitting and scanning through page after page in backend trying to find stock that is only on one website. Is there any search option which will let me search for products that ISN'T on a particular site? That way I could speed up the process a lot.